# Calculate all number in array except Max value and Min value and zero values

Tags: c#, arrays, lambda

I have some numbers that I get from text-boxes and I want to calculate average of these numbers :

```
float t1 = float.Parse(textBox1.Text);
float t2 = float.Parse(textBox2.Text);
float t3 = float.Parse(textBox3.Text);
float t4 = float.Parse(textBox4.Text);
float t5 = float.Parse(textBox5.Text);
float t6 = float.Parse(textBox6.Text);
float t7 = float.Parse(textBox7.Text);
float[] array = { t1,t2,t3,t4,t5,t6,t7};
float final_Score = array.Average();
```

but I Don't want to `Max` value and `Min` value participant on this calculation:

```
float final_Score = array.Average()-(array.Max())-(array.Min());
```

now my question in that I wanna get average for non-zero numbers, how can I do that?

another question :
I wanna change back color of textBoxes that are `Max` and `Min` for non-zero numbers too.

```
Controls.OfType<TextBox>().Where(x => x.Text == array.Max().ToString()).FirstOrDefault().BackColor = Color.Red;
Controls.OfType<TextBox>().Where(x => x.Text == array.Min().ToString()).FirstOrDefault().BackColor = Color.Red;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For either solution, use:

```
int min = array.Min();
int max = array.Max();
```

and then either:

```
float finalScore = array.Except(array.Where(a => a == 0 
                                              || a == min 
                                              || a == max))
                        .Average();
```

or alternatively:

```
float finalScore = array.Where(a => a != 0 
                                 && a != min  
                                 && a != max)
                        .Average();
```

And finally, to answer the problem OP ran into with this, if you need to filter 0s and the smallest value above 0 then you'll have to do (instead of the original `int min` line):

```
int min = array.Where(a => a > 0).Min();
```

Comment: The Min() and Max() methods with be called for every array element. This is probably not an issue in this case where the array only consists of seven elements.

Comment: Thanks simon, fixed that.

Comment: thanks a lot @RobG what about changing color of textboxes for max and min values?

Comment: `array = Controls.OfType<TextBox>().Where(a => int.Parse(a.Text) == min || int.Parse(a.Text) == max).Color = ...;`

Comment: I am getting this error : `'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Windows.Forms.TextBox>' does not contain a definition for 'Color' and no extension method 'Color' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Windows.Forms.TextBox>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`

Comment: The actual property is BackColor or ForeColor depending on which color you want to change. I hope this helps.

Comment: @RobG why I can get two different result in each of your code?

Comment: one more thing is that in each of them I am getting wrong result

Comment: @RobG for example my array contains `20,5,5,1` in this case it should `5+5= 10` (should omit max and min values) but with your code I am getting `11` in result, it seems that it calculates min value, means `5+5+1=11`

Comment: If 0 was your min value, then you need to remove 0s before you try to remove any other min value. That is why you got that problem.

Comment: so how can I do that?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35535/discussion-between-sirwan-afifi-and-rob-g)